# Custom UIView Class Constraints Depending on ParentView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile, applet

I'm making a custom UIView class that hold a datepicker. I want to setup the view constraints to reference the parent view that will call my custom class. here is my following code. this is what i get
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    var datepicker:UIDatePicker!
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupConstraints()
    } // initiliaze the button like this CustomButton()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    }

    func setupDatePicker() {
        let datepicker = UIDatePicker()
        datepicker.minimumDate = Date()
    }

    func setupConstraints(){
        setupDatePicker()

        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true // the error occurs here
        trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
        centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        backgroundColor = .red


        addSubview(datepicker)
        datepicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        datepicker.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        datepicker.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        datepicker.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        datepicker.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true



    }


}
```

and this is where i create my custom view and launch it

```
    var customView: CustomView!

class ListViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
         customView = CustomView()
         view.addSubview(customView)
         view.bringSubviewToFront(customView)
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not assigning `var datepicker:UIDatePicker!` so it is `nil`.
Try:

```
func setupDatePicker() {
    let datepicker = UIDatePicker()
    datepicker.minimumDate = Date()
    self.datepicker = datepicker
}
```

Comment: it did not work man :/ i have assigned datepicker with a new instance of class UIDatePicker already

Comment: OK so the issue is `superview!`, it is still `nil` at `init` time

Comment: yes seems so how do i assign my custom view a superview that is the view where it created?

Comment: Implement `func willMove(toSuperview newSuperview: UIView?)` and setup the constraints there.

Comment: sorry you should override `didMoveToSuperview()`